# How can I git commit --no-edit but take the author name/email of last commit as well?

Tags: git

Our CI build does a git merge --squash $BRANCH into master and then does a git commit --no-edit and if the build passes, it pushes master (Our CI is the only one who can push to master).

However, currently our git logs look like so

[image]

I would prefer to set the message perhaps to branch name+ all squashed commits (adding -m clears out all squashed commits :( ), set the user to the last commit username and set the email to last commit email.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the committer name and email when you do the squash by setting the `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` environment variables to an appropriate value.  That will override the default and allow you to customize it.

As for modifying the message, you don't really want `--no-edit`, because you do want to edit it, but you also don't want `-m`, because that overrides the entire message.  What you really want is a script that edits your commit message to be used as the editor.

You can indeed specify such a script using `GIT_EDITOR`, and it should take a single argument as the name of the file to edit, it should edit it in place (or overwrite the file with your copy), and it should exit 0.  If you're using a standard Unix environment, a shell script that calls a program such as `ex` or `ed` may be a good choice.  You could also use `sed` to write to a temporary file and then `mv` over the original file.

So your invocation would end up looking something like this:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$(git log -1 --format=%an "$BRANCH")" \
  GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$(git log -1 --format=%ae "$BRANCH")" \
  GIT_EDITOR="script/to/merge-editor" \
  git merge --squash "$BRANCH"
```